# R support vector machine - support vectors have too many features

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

When I train my SVM the output support vectors have many more features than my input data. In the below example I use a small subset of the data (10 rows of 6 features to predict a binary class) but the support vectors have 13 features:

```
library(e1071)

A10 <- c("t","t","f","f","t","f","f","f","t","t")
A11 <- c(1,12,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,6)
A12 <- c("f","t","f","t","f","f","f","f","t","f")
A13 <- c("g","g","s","g","g","g","s","g","g","g")
A14 <- c("00202","00129","00080","00000","00232","00360","00080","00076","00312","00000")
A15 <- c(0,3,0,0,100,0,0,0,150,200)
Class <- c("+","-","-","-","+","-","-","-","+","-")
df <- data.frame(A10, A11, A12, A13, A14, A15, Class)

mysvm <- svm(df$Class ~ ., data = df)

print(ncol(mysvm$SV))
```

Looking at `mysvm$SV` above, it seems to have mangled some of the data with the feature names. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: All your variables are treated as factors because they are encoded as strings. If this is not desired behaviour, make A11, A14 and A15 numeric, not strings.

Comment: If I look at str(df) it shows A11 and A15 are numeric, A14 is a factor as I want them to be.    But that doesn't explain why the support vectors have more than 6 features?

Comment: Features are the number of free parameters that must be estimated, not the number of columns in your data. A factor with k levels results in k parameters. You should look to Crossvalidated for more help. Programatically, the following should give you a better understand of what R is doing: `model.matrix(attr(model.frame(Class ~., df), "terms"), df)`. That is the actual dataframe that you are appying your algorithm to.

Comment: Thank very much for that.  My misunderstanding was an expectation that the support vectors were instances of the training data i.e. in the same format with the same columns.  But I see from your helpful reply that the factors have been broken down into binary variables for each level.